# Will cloneing current SSD C: drive to larger capacity drive cause software (licensing) problems?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I currently have a Windows 10 PC with an SSD C: drive which is running low on space. (Note: second HD is standard drive containing D:, F:, and H: and I'm not planning to do anything on with it/them.) I'd like to purchase larger capacity SSD drive to replace just current the C: SSD.

If I install it as I: and clone the C: to it, then make it bootable with 'bcdboot':

1. Do I make it the new C:? In the PC's BIOS or ?
2. Will software realize this is a new drive (same PC) and cause problems with licensing? (Know you don't know all that I have on the drive but I'm mostly concerned with Microsoft Win10)

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Your storage device has no impact on your Windows 10 installation activation status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm mostly concerned with Microsoft Win10

Well I have good news, you needn't be concerned in that particular arena. Your Windows 10 license should activate automatically, as a hard drive swap shouldn't trigger any of Microsoft's hardware detection. How they run their hardware recognition is fairly ambiguous, but I've never seen a report of Win10 refusing to activate over such a minor hardware replacement.

You will also be glad to hear that your Win10 license can also be linked to your Microsoft account. If you're currently using a local account, simply make a MS account and use it solely to store your license. You can then login and activate after the hard drive replacement, and simply revert your account back to a local one. This feature was implemented in the Win10 Anniversary Update.

As a third option, there are a plethora of tricks you can use to get an activated copy of Win10 running... even on a machine it has never been installed to. These seem to be mostly loopholes left over from the free upgrade process, but they have a significant enough success rate that you may want to try that option if MS ends up locking you out of your licensed copy of Windows. I will not go into those options in detail, because this is not the forum for such information and to call those tactics "grey-hat" would be putting it mildly.

Generally speaking, the biggest issue people run into with cloning drives is broken registry keys so you might have to re-install a few programs. Usually everything else is fine, but create a full backup of your data just in case.